# How to make an App to switch to HTTP in facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page, but I dont have a SSL with me, so its always with the HTTP connection. So when I open the App Page (Canvas), I get an error within the iFrame `Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.` which is obvious due to the FB calling for HTTPS version of the page. But I noticed that some pages ask for "`Switch to Regular HTTP Connection`" to view the page. I was wondering how to do that, I googled a lot but couldn't find the relevant information.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a url set for https on your app's settings page? You should leave it blank if you don't have a valid SSL page yet, and then it should give you the prompt to switch to regular http.  However, you will want to get an SSL certificate soon as Facebook is recommending users switch to always-on SSL and at some point SSL may be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

"Switch to Regular HTTP Connection" is limited to admins (at least without so many scary warnings) so it's important that you get an SSL connection running if you're going to have an app on FB now.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently Discovered the following error because the SSL was expired.

```
This webpage is not available
The webpage at https://example.com/facebook/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
```

Renewed the SSL and all fixed